# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'has_z'

Tags: python, geopandas, attributeerror

I got the following `GeoDataFrame` taken from a CSV file and after some slincing and `CRS` and `geometry` asignment

```
    ctf_nom         geometry                                    id      
0   Prunus mahaleb  POINT (429125.795043319 4579664.7564311)    2616    
1   Betula pendula  POINT (425079.292045901 4585098.09043407)   940     
2   Betula pendula  POINT (425088.115045896 4585093.66943407)   940     
3   Abelia triflora POINT (429116.661043325 4579685.93743111)   2002    
4   Abies alba      POINT (428219.962044021 4587346.66843531)   797
```

I've converted the `geometry` from a `str` trough:

```
from shapely import wkt

df['geometry'] = df['geometry'].apply(wkt.loads)
df_geo = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry = 'geometry')
```

and asigned a crs by :

```
df_geo.crs = {'init' :'epsg:25831'}
df_geo.crs
```

when I'm trying to save again the reduced geodataframe by  `gdf.to_file()` function it returns the following attribute error:

```
out = r'my_path\df_geo.geojson'
df_geo.to_file(out, driver = 'GeoJSON')
```

It's even the same when I try with `shp` extension...

`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'has_z'`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 6):

Since it's a calculated geometry, you have to explicitly set it as geometry for the `GeoDataFrame`.

try using something like this -

```
geodf.set_geometry(col='geometry', inplace=True)
```